# atomic exchange vs compare_exchange_xxx

Tags: c++, atomic

```
bool expected = false;
extern std::atomic<bool> current; // set somewhere else
while (!current.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true)
       && !expected);
```

What is the need to use this code versus `current.exchange(expected)` ?

Does `exchange` can induce some race condition ?

edited: same question versus `current.store(expected)`

Comment: It may depend what's happening in the other thread(s) which modify `current`.  What are they doing?

Comment: in fact my question in more about education purpose, there is some differences if others thread do current.store or current.exchange ?

Answer (score 1):

`exchange` and `compare_exchange_weak` have different semantics in general, but in your example it doesn't look like you're relying on any behavior that would demonstrate that.  If you have two or more threads that are racing to write the same value, it doesn't matter who gets there first, and in fact you don't even need the protection of std::atomic.  To understand the differences, you'd have to look at an example where the behavior of a given thread would depend on what had happened before it arrived at the point of calling `exchange` or `compare_exchange_weak`.